# Cortana channel - Failed to create bot module

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm using Azure Bot Channels Registration for my bot, I have working endpoint and bot works well in Web Chat and My settings are:

`Display Name: Engine Crave
Invocation Name: Engine Crave
Long Desc, Short Desc etc are all correct and filled and also organization at the last is also selected.`


Also, My bot takes no user permissions. But when I save the Cortana Channel, I get a popup:
`Unable to save.
There was an error saving the channel:
Failed to create bot module. Trace Id : 87140f58-46f8-4101-a849-17d63af6831c`

Trace ID always keeps changing whenever I try.
Pls help!

Comment: Cortana has recently introduced the knowledge.store portal for cortana skills  following [this tutorial](https://help.knowledge.store/tutorials_code_samples/cortana_skill/index.html) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yayay! I found answer myself. Go-to settings and make display name same as your bot registration name when you registered on Azure! Mine was `crave-engine`.

Next goto Channels Registration -> Cortana -> Here you will see 

`Display Name: crave-engine
Invocation Name: crave-engine`

Let these be like this and just click the "Register" button at the bottom. It's ok for now, You can however change these names When you register from https://knowledge.store .

I don't know these was some kind of bug or Azure Bot Team did this on purpose!