# Unable to connect Web App Bot to Cortana Channel

Tags: botframework

I'm trying to add the Cortana channel to a bot I've been working on today. However, when the page loads, the entire form is greyed out except for the knowledge.store Register button, and the Cancel button.

I've read elsewhere that people have managed to get past this by clicking really quickly on the Save button that appears briefly as the page loads, but I've had no luck with that. The (very helpful) tech support guy suggests it could be due to special characters or numbers in the bot name, but I have the exact same issue with a bot name that's just lowercase letters.

**UPDATE:** I can now see my knowledge.store organisations in a dropdown next to the Register button. Clicking the Register button throws a "Failed to create bot module" error. I am able to connect the channel successfully on another bot I made to test the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cortana channel - Failed to create bot module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989370/cortana-channel-failed-to-create-bot-module)

Comment: does the duplicate link help you?